# PyroCMS how to call codeigniter helper in template?

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, pyrocms

I would like to add codeigniter helper to template.

For example:

```
{{ helper:redirect uri="/order/images/" method="refresh" }}
```

but it doesn't work. It is possible to call standart helper this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know is it right way but it works:

```
class Plugin_AvHelper extends Plugin_Helper
{
    public function redirect()
    {
            $uri        = $this->attribute('uri');
        $method     = $this->attribute('method');

        return $uri && $method ? redirect($uri, $method) : NULL;
    }
}
```

and to call:

```
{{ avhelper:redirect uri="/order/images/" method="refresh" }}
```